# MS Access SQL query for active assigned cases

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've inherited an Access database and am looking to start using it to do reporting. I've written a query that gets me the information I'm looking for, I'm just hoping someone can have a look over it and tell me if I'm doing it the wrong way or not.

Anyway, the query takes information from 3 tables:

- `sites` - more detailed information on each workplace
- `employees` - list of employees and their associated workplace
- `cases` - holds the bulk of the information needed for the report

I want most fields from the cases table as this is how work is tracked, but I want to also group by the city which is in the `sites` table and by employee name from the `employees` table.

```
SELECT 
    sites.city, 
    employees.[first name], 
    employees.[last name], 
    cases.[assigned to], 
    cases.ref, 
    cases.status, 
    cases.priority, 
    cases.[opened date], 
    Round(Now()-cases.[opened date],0) AS Age
FROM
    cases 
LEFT JOIN 
    (employees LEFT JOIN sites ON employees.site = sites.site) 
ON 
    cases.[assigned to] = employees.username
WHERE 
    cases.[assigned to]<>"Not Assigned" 
AND 
    cases.status="Active" 
AND 
    cases.priority<>"first contact"
ORDER BY 
    sites.city, 
    employees.[first name], 
    employees.[last name], 
    cases.[opened date] desc;
```

Is there any stupid rookie mistakes in here that I've fallen prey to? Could that be done any better? Have I not given enough information in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any major flaw in this query.

I would just make the Jointures like this, as it's more clear :

```
SELECT 
    sites.city, 
    employees.[first name], 
    employees.[last name], 
    cases.[assigned to], 
    cases.ref, 
    cases.status, 
    cases.priority, 
    cases.[opened date], 
    Round(Now()-cases.[opened date],0) AS Age
FROM ((cases 
LEFT JOIN employees ON cases.[assigned to] = employees.username)
LEFT JOIN sites ON employees.site = sites.site)
WHERE cases.[assigned to]<>"Not Assigned" 
  AND cases.status="Active" 
  AND cases.priority<>"first contact"
ORDER BY 
    sites.city, 
    employees.[first name], 
    employees.[last name], 
    cases.[opened date] desc;
```

If you can't have any case with non existing employees and sites, it's better to change your 2 LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN. Just throw the 2 queries and compare the results.

In your `WHERE` clause, having some `<>` is generally inefficient on large tables. It's always better to make a `IN()` and list all the possibilities excluding "*Not assigned*" or "*first contact*" :

1. If  `cases.[assigned to]` can only contain an employee username or "Not Assigned", then just doing an `INNER JOIN` on the employee table will automatically filter the *not assigned* and you don't need to specify it in the `WHERE` clause.
2. if you have a limited number of `case.priority` values, list them all but "*first contact*" : `AND cases.priority IN ("priority1", "super urgent", "can wait")`

For the Age, if you want to compute the days from your open_date, it's better to do :

```
dateDiff("d",Now(),cases.[opened date]) AS Age
```

you can also concatenate the first and last name in one column:

```
 (employees.[last name] & ' ' & employees.[first name]) AS EmpName,
```

That's all what comes to my mind.

Comment: I appreciate the tips. I had always assumed a NOT clause would be less taxing because it only dealt with one value instead of several. I'll have to do more reading.

Comment: The *different than* operator is a perf killer for all RDBMS I know. It often results in full table scan

Answer (score 1):

The nested joins are unconventional. A "flat chain" would be the more common and readable way to write it.

```
FROM cases 
    LEFT JOIN employees
        ON cases.[assigned to] = employees.username
    LEFT JOIN sites
        ON employees.site = sites.site
```

SQL string literal a should be written using single quotes. Double quotes may be accepted by MS Access (and MySQL), but they are nonstandard and [could be interpreted differently](//stackoverflow.com/a/1992392/1157100) in standard-compliant databases.

```
WHERE 
    cases.[assigned to] <> 'Not Assigned' AND 
    cases.status = 'Active' AND 
    cases.priority <> 'first contact'
```

You shouldn't be using `'Not Assigned'` as a special value, though. It's bad practice to use values with special significance that might also be valid data — even if this special value is less likely to occur than [`'Null'`](//stackoverflow.com/q/4456438/1157100) or [`'XXXXXXX'`](http://www.snopes.com/autos/law/noplate.asp). If there really isn't anyone assigned to the case, use a `NULL` to indicate that fact, and use `WHERE cases.[assigned to] IS NOT NULL` in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I inherited the design where `'Not Assigned'` was a value instead of null which does seem like the logical choice. I'll certainly be looking to change it in the future.